# How can we calculate coords of the end point if we know start point, distance and angle?

Tags: javascript, math, coordinates, angle

We know the start point, the angle and the distance between start and end points.

```
let x1 = 500;
let y1 = 500;
let angle = 45;
let distance = 100;
```

How can we calculate the coordinates of the end point?

[image]

It must be some method like Math.atan2...

Comment: What have you tried so far? It looks like this is a homework problem :D SO people are here to help you get un-stuck, not solve problems from the beginning (usually) :D

Comment: Question is about JS methods

Comment: Yep so you know how to calculate the end point in math but don't know which javascript function corresponds to the math equation(s)? Maybe you can make that clear in your question & add some of your research - have you found something similar that looks like it should work but doesn't?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate point, given x, y, angle, and distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143932/calculate-point-given-x-y-angle-and-distance)

Comment: solve the math problem first ... then "translate" your math into javascript (and yes it has to do with trigonometry - sin, cos, tan)

Comment: You can easily calculate the coordinate using JavaScript sine and cosine, i.e., [Math.sin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sin) and [Math.cos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/cos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Javascript, given the theta angle, and the length of the hypotenuse, find the opposite and adjacent sides:

```js
let x1 = y1 = 500, // starting point
  hyp = 100, // hypotenuse
  theta_deg = 45, // theta angle in degrees
  rad = (parseFloat(theta_deg) * Math.PI) / 180, // convert deg to radians
  
  // opp = hyp * sin(θ)
  opp = Math.round((hyp * Math.sin(rad)) * 100) / 100, // opposite side
  
  // adj = √( (hyp * hyp) - (opp * opp) )
  adj = Math.round((Math.sqrt((hyp * hyp) - (opp * opp))) * 100) / 100, // adjacent side
  x2 = x1 + adj, y2 = y1 + opp; // end point

console.log('opposite side:', opp, ' adjacent side:', adj);
console.log('end point coord. = x2:', x2, ' y2:', y2);
```

**Note:** degrees must be converted to [radians](https://www.math.net/radian) before applying to Javascript [Math](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) sine methods.

```
let deg = 45;
let rad = (parseFloat(deg) * Math.PI) / 180;
// 0.7853981633974483
```

Answer (score 2):

found it

```js
let angle = 45, distance = 100, x1 = 500, y1 = 500;
let x2 = Math.round(Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * distance + x1);
let y2 = Math.round(Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * distance + y1);
console.log(x2, y2);
```